# Java - Memory out of exception error while processing 25000 records and Above in xls using POI

Tags: java, oracle11g, apache-poi, jxls

We tried with increasing the Heap Memory  to 512 MB. but still the problem persist.We  have used this as using Java Stored Procedure in Oracle Data base.Please refer the source code

```
        XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();          
        InputStream is = pTemplate.getBinaryStream();

        // seems to be slow for large resultsets
        HSSFWorkbook resultWorkbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, beans);
        is.close();
        // write output stream to CLOB          
        java.io.OutputStream os = newBlob.setBinaryStream(1L);          
        os.flush();
```

Comment: Can you post your OOM stacktrace and tell us what this code is doing (what are XLSTransformer, pTemplate, beans etc)?

Comment: You may add an option to dump the Heap on OOM and use Eclipse memory analyzer (or similar) to check the heap usage. May help to find unexpected issues. And another issue: Try to close the stream after finish writing and call "free()" if not used anymore. There is an issue the oracle JDBC driver and blob if I remember well.

Comment: There is no class `XLSTransformer` in Apache POI - where is that coming from? And does the problem go away if you just use normal Apache POI classes?

Comment: For XLSTransformer - please referred from net.sf.jxls.transformer.XLSTransformer;